# Did i take the wrong path? securing my website and restfull api using MVC4 and WebAPI?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure

Its been a few years without working with dot.net and MVC and a week ago i decided to look at it for creating a business application for an idea I came up with. Alot happened since, MVC 4 and Azure. I really like Azure as it was fast and easy to deploy and will be easy to scale up if it hit off.

I found some topics on securing a WCF API using the Azure ACS and may have gotten abit narrow minded - atleast i vent down the path and created my solution in MVC 4. Creating a Website that also exposes and WebAPI. One week later I managed to get my site publised to azure with WIF enabled. Users can log in using ACS and the providers provided there.

Today i was looking abit around within MVC 4 and stuff that have been added since i last worked with MVC. Some nice features came along. I then discovered how it look like there as default are implementet/enabled features to use OAuthWebSecurity and people could login and create users with their Social Networks Accounts.

So have i wasted all my time getting ACS up and running together with WIF I ask myself?

Can anyone take a moment to talk abit about, or link to some topics that covers following:
What do i gain from using WIF and claim based authentication over just the OauthWebSecurity that have been setup as default in a MVC 4 Project?

I have been searched on google and read alot, and do have some basic information, but I would love to have the best practice or short facts summarized.

(Will put a bounty on it to get some good answers when available, but feel free to answer before).

Answer (score 0):

If you have ACS up and running and it all works, then I wouldn't change it unless you have a specific reason.  ACS implements the same features that WebSecurity does with OAuth and using OAuth providers...  You're probably better off with ACS, as it's a well debugged system and you don't have to maintain it.